# Can you count how many values are in an 'in' operator?

Tags: sql

Using retail as an example, I'm trying to find out how many members have less than 5 items I have listed (defined by a.SKU). I used an 'in' operator to define all of the SKUs I want to look at, but I keep getting an 'Incorrect syntax near keyword 'JOIN' error. It's the second JOIN that's giving me the issue.
For reference, SKU is a string field.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
    SELECT D1.*, COUNT(a.SKU) as SKUcount, a.SKU FROM [Main Database] D1

    JOIN [Unique TKRS Users] r 
    On r.memberID = D1.MemberID

    JOIN ENT.[AddedToList] a
    ON D1.MemberID = a.MemberID
    AND a.SKU IN ('883049325743','817096012486','28295188661','17817783217','10942225058','838810018591','11120225433','885609013503','622356529860','86279027443')
    GROUP BY a.MemberID
    HAVING SKUCount < 5
```

Comment: inner join, left join right join, cross join... need to know which.  and I'm assuming [Unique TKRS users] is a valid table/view name  also... group by w/o listing all non-aggregrated objects is not generally supported.  This looks to be SQL server given the []'s notation; which has never supported partial group by to my knowledge.

Comment: this might be a nuance with the specific sql platform you're using. can you add to your post what is the database flavor you're using?

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.